# Come back from third window to first window in history

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm developing a Windows Phone application and I have three screens:

1. Main screen
2. Login selection screen.
3. Sign in screen.

When user has signed in and push "sign in" button I want to come back from screen 3 to screen 1.
Now I come back to screen 2 and  immediately to first one. I don't want to show 2 screen.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Assume your pages are named as FirstPage.xaml, SecondPage.xaml, ThirdPage.xaml

```
//Check for the first page and remove the remaining back stack in your ThirdPage.xaml

  while(!NavigationService.BackStack.First().Source.OriginalString.Contains("FirstPage"))
  {
      NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
  }

  NavigationService.GoBack();
```

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in page 3 add

```
NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
```

This will remove page 2 from the back stack. Now when the user hits the back key, he'll navigate directly backwards to page 1.

But as Amal Dev noted, Microsoft wants you to let the user navigate to the previous page. This rule doesn't seem to be enforced too much, it's probably meant as "never ever confuse the user". If you confuse the certificating tester, your app will fail certification.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `NavigationService.Navigate` method for this.

```
  NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri( string.Format("/your page name.xaml?val={0}", ValueTextBox.Text), UriKind.Relative));
```

Please refer the link given below.

[Simple Navigation In Windows Phone 7](http://geekswithblogs.net/PeterTweed/archive/2010/05/17/simple-navigation-in-windows-mobile-7.aspx)

Comment: But, if user taps on back button, will it back from first screen to third?

Comment: No. According to Microsoft, ideally if you press the back button the control should go back only to the previous page, not to some other page. But you can find a workaround here http://beta.blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/jgold/archive/2012/05/23/back-button-windows-phone-certification.aspx

Comment: But if I use your code I have this navigation history: first -> second -> third -> first. I user taps on back button he will be back to third screen.

Comment: I had done an edit on the previous comment. Please refer the link in that

Comment: Yes. Since its the previous page. Backbutton will act as a history back button. It navigates backwards through the backstack.